# How to get PHPmyadmin access on subdomain ubuntu

Tags: apache, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to setup a subdomain for accessing phpmyadmin

PS: that i haven't installed phpmyadmin using package manager, i've downloaded from the official website and uploaded to `/var/www/phpmyadmin`

I'm using below host config in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/phpmyadmin/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ServerName pma.somedomain.in
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phpmyadmin

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =pma.somedomain.in
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I've also set vhost for SSL connection, whenever i call the URL `pma.somedomain.in` it loads but shows default Apache page.

How do i get the phpmyadmin access here?

Comment: what you set in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` is `pma.somedomain.in` but the URL you access is `pma.somedomain.com`?

Comment: It was a typo error, i've updated it

Comment: Stupid question, but did you reload apache?

Comment: yes i reloaded apache, checked for error and followed every tutorial online, but ended up with no luck

Comment: One thing I can imagine is that the default directive is above the PHPMyAdmin directive. You need to have the subdomain directives above the default one, otherwise the default directive will match first.

Comment: When you restarted Apache, did you do `sudo apachectl restart`, `reload` or `stop` and then `start`? If you didn't stop it and then started it again, try that. I've had many issues through out the years with Apache not caring about changes unless I manually stop and start it.

Comment: i used `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Comment: Try: `sudo apachectl stop && sudo apachectl start` and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: it's the same as earlier, no diff

Comment: @Realitätsverlust did not get you?

Answer (score 0):

On debian/ubuntu you have 2 directories

1. /etc/apache2/sites-available (available sites)
2. /etc/apache2/sites-enable (sites enable)

When you create a site all your configurations are located on sites-available, all sites configuration have to end with the ext .conf. When you want to activate a site you just create a symbolic link from the sites-available to the sites-enable.

```
ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enable/000-default.conf
```

Always is good to add an alias to include www.

```
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias www.domain.com
```

Changes to the configuration require an apache reboot.

```
sudo service apache2 restart 
or 
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

I usually create a different configuration for each virtual host and leave the default configuration for the default site if exists or none. In case someone scans all open ports on my machine will get a default empty site or if a user request the site using an ip address instead of a domain.

Also verify that the domain name is resolving to your IP address, sometimes DNS takes some time to propagate.

```
nslookup domain.com
```

If you can not wait, you can also add the domain/ip address to your host file.

For example in linux and MAC [/etc/hosts] on windows [C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts]

```
10.0.0.2 sub.domain.com
```

Comment: When i ran the command it gave me below message `ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf': File exists`

Comment: you already have the sybolic link, verify that it is pointing at your config file by doing an ls -la on your /etc/apache2/sites-enable directory.

Comment: he can add an alias to the subdomain www.subdomain.domain.com, if he does not create the symbolic link the default configuration will be used and the virtual host file is not going to be considered.

Comment: precisely, 1- we want to check that the symbolic link is there and its pointing correctly 2- a lot of people still use www in front of everything, it does not hurt to have it. it is call best practices.

Comment: It's done :D, i had some config problems in my conf file, i had craeted too many if confitions to check modules, when i merged all the code into 1 if condition, it worked :)

Comment: @Magnus Eriksoon see it for yourself www.aws.amazon.com ,www in front of a subdomain. If you don't like it fine, but you are not working o creating a site for yourself you create a site for your users the public. ;) that's why it is called best practices.

Comment: that's true, not everybody follow the best practices ;